# Minimum arrow weight of a Bear Archery Grizzly bow

Tags: gear, archery, bows, arrows

What's the minimum arrow weight in grains per pound (GPP) of a Bear Archery Grizzly? It's a 2015 model with 35# if that matters.

Comment: You mean for the "too light=dry fire" thing? As for the actual selection on charts it doesnt matter whats on the label: you have to take in account the draw weight at *your actual* draw length.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren The model matters a lot. The GPP is different for each manufacturer and sometimes even for the models. A Bear bow has normally 8,5 gpp which is pretty high compared to other manufactures. I just wanted to make sure that the 8,5 applies to the 2015 Grizzly. I'm afraid that I could save some arrow-weight (what results in speed of course).

Comment: Lets clarify: I didnt mean the model, I meant the label poundage, as per finding the right arrow etc etc etc. and that was a separate comment  from my question about the completely different issue of using an arrow so light that its as bad for the bow as dry firing, since I wasnt sure if you referred to that. My comment above was referring to two different issues

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, misunderstood that. However, I knew that I have to use the actual draw weight and not the #@28" of course.

Comment: AFAIK, there is a standard rule is aprox more or less 5GPP. So, as long your arrows are "same" weight, you should be good but if you want to be that precise, your best bet is to contact the manufactures.

Comment: @Desorder The normal case for Bear bows is 8,5GPP. I want to make sure that this also applies to the Grizzly. I thought that I ask the question here and see if somebody already contacted the manufacturer. It's kind of silly that everyone googles, finds no results and then asks Bear Archery directly^^

Answer (score 1):

Most recurves and selfbows I have shot behave best with an arrow that is close to or at 10GPP.  My definition of behave though is related to performance related to hunting - I want a heavier arrow to have more kinetic energy downrange.  I shoot no less than 9GPP, the lighter arrows just have to much string twang for me and makes me nervous.

I'd start with 10GPP and then work my way up or down depending on your arrow flight and penetration.